# HTML5 Video Respnsive Vertical Cover

Tags: css, html, video, responsive-design, cover

Is there a way to make a HTML5 video (and the poster attribute) to act like a centered background cover?

I've created a dummy pen you can play around width:

http://codepen.io/SEFarstad/pen/vujqE

The layout is based on two 50% width sections, where the left one will contain the fixed video and the right one will containt the absolute positioned content.

The main problem is that my design needs to be split vertically, making horizontal videos an issue. Is there a way to make these horizontal videos full height in a vertically based layout it like this? *-in the same manner as you use background-size: cover;*

I know you can use background videos etc but I need this to have controls, posters and so on to meet some interactivity demands I have on this project.

Comment: Do you mean to say your videos height should be equal to that of right coulmn content?

Comment: Why you use position absolute and fixed??

Comment: You can simply use float left&right fot these two box. The right box may be with overflow-x: scrolling. So, you won't have the problem with bg.

Comment: No, @PrasannaAarthi. The left side height should be equal to the height of the browser window.

Comment: @ITChristian; the left side is supposed to be fixed and cover 50% of the browser windows height and width. While the right side will be scrollable. But this isn't really the problem is it? The issue is to get the poster and video to cover the left side.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and you've probably moved on to other things, but I wanted to answer just in case anybody else stumbles on to this via Google. What you were looking for was `object-fit`, a way to add that kind of behavior to videos and images. [Here's some info on it](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css3-object-fit-object-position/), but basically you just need to write it like this:

```
video {
  ... // other stuff here
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Sadly, you [can't use this on every browser just yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit). However, there's [a polyfill you can look into](https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit).